# Recognize variables inside a expression string in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to create a function in jquery where I have some input field (numbers)...and a final input field text named formula.

Input fields for numbers can be added dinamically and each one as an ID with `LETTERS` AND `_` ONLY to unique identifier as variable for expression.

Inside input fields (for numbers) i can only insert `digits` and `dot`.

Inside formula i can create a text expression like: `((a + b) / c) + 10`

For formula input I can ONLY insert: `digits . ( ) + - * /` and letters `a` to `z`

I need to detect and extract from a formula, all variables. So I can iterate all document to search variable by id and collect each value.

Calculation is not a problem i can use the `jquery expression builder plugin`.

I need only to detect the variable inside the formula string.

So in a real example:

```
<input type="text" id="variable_a" value="16">

<input type="text" id="varb" value="4">

<input type="text" id="c" value="2">

<input type="text" id="formula" value="(a + b) / c + 10">

<button id="btn">CALCULATE</button>

...

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").on("click", function() {

       var formula = $("#formula").val();

       // HELP TO DETECT VARIABLES INSIDE STRING (THEY ARE ONLY LETTERS AND _ )???

       ...

       // I NEED TO CREATE THIS ARRAY BUT HOW???

       var options_formula = {
         variables: [
        {
          name: 'a',
          value: 16
        },
        {
          name: 'b',
          value: 4
        },
        {
          name: 'c',
          value: 2
        }
        ]
       };

       var expBuilder = $(#formula).expressionBuilder(options_formula);

       alert(expBuilder.runExpression());

   });
});
```

Anyone as a suggestion how to detects variables ( letters or letters with _ ) from formula string?

Comment: Sorry, but this is just too broad. You've given a large number of requirements, and an exceptionally limited amount of "example" code... so it would appear that you to expect us to write the majority of the rest of it for you, which we're simply not here to do. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular

Comment: Hi I can simplify the problem in this way: variables are all enclosed by [ ]. So i need a .match function with regular expression to detect all string enclosed inside the brackets.

Comment: Then I would recommend you do some research into reg-ex patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use [mathjs parser](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html#parser).

In order to get all the variable names you may use [Expression trees: traverse() callback](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/expression_trees.html):

```
var scope = {};
formulaParsed.traverse(function (node, path, parent) {
    if (node.type == 'SymbolNode') {
        var val = +$('#variable_' + node.name).val();
        scope[node.name] = isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;
    }
});
```

Now your issue is how to link a variable name to an input field. I adapted the IDs.

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function (e) {
    var formula = $('#formula').val();
    var formulaParsed = math.parse(formula);

    var scope = {};

    formulaParsed.traverse(function (node, path, parent) {
        if (node.type == 'SymbolNode') {
            var val = +$('#variable_' + node.name).val();
            scope[node.name] = isNaN(val) ? 0 : val;
        }
    });

    console.log(scope);

    var formulaCompiled = formulaParsed.compile();
    try {
        var result = formulaCompiled.evaluate(scope);
        $('#result').val(result);
    } catch (e) {
        $('#result').val(e.message);
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/6.0.3/math.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="variable_a" value="16">

<input type="text" id="variable_b" value="4">

<input type="text" id="variable_c" value="2">

<input type="text" id="formula" value="(a + b) / c + 10">

<input type="text" id="result" value="">

<button id="btn">CALCULATE</button>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for code example. But scope variable has to be created dinamically. So I need to detect variables inside the formula first... here the names of variables are "hardwritten" in the code

Comment: Hi @gaetanoM probably I can't explain the problem better. Assuming I 've a button to add a new dynamic input <button id="btn-addInput">ADD</button> and add an input with a random id like 'varJ'... if in the formula i insert a + varJ..... varJ is not associated cause the scope variable in the example manage only a , b, c

Comment: @GiuseppeLodiRizzini Answer updated. Let me know. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @gaetanoM !!! Your code is perfect. In meanwhile I have created a workaround for my question but your code is much better! No problem for link variable names i've already a function for this. Thanks